# self.start_error_message) in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ALPA AGRAWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\ALPA AGRAWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 769, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\ALPA AGRAWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1172, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wd.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
  File "C:\Users\ALPA AGRAWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\ALPA AGRAWAL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromdriver.exe ' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Well, "'chromdriver.exe ' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home" - have you ensured that `chromedriver.exe` exists on your system and is in `PATH`?